# How do you relabel variables and values in Stata fast?

Tags: stata

**Currently recoding a household survey dataset with 300+ variables.**

**1. It would be too inefficient though if I name the variables one-by-one. Is there any way to relabel all in a few lines of code?****

This is the dictionary file of two of my variables `lc03_rel` (relationship to household head) and `lc04_sex` (sex of the household head:

```
[Item]
Label=C03-Relationship to Household Head
Name=LC03_REL
Start=27
Len=2
ZeroFill=Yes

[ValueSet]
Label=C03-Relationship to Household Head
Name=LC03_REL_VS1
Value=1;Head
Value=2;Wife/Spouse
Value=3;Son/daughter
Value=4;Brothers/sisters
Value=5;Son/daughter_law
Value=6;Grandchildren
Value=7;Father/Mother
Value=8;Other Relative
Value=9;Boarder
Value=10;Domestic Helper
Value=11;Non_Relative

[Item]
Label=C04-Sex
Name=LC04_SEX
Start=29
Len=1
ZeroFill=Yes

[ValueSet]
Label=C04-Sex
Name=LC04_SEX_VS1
Value=1;Male
Value=2;Female
```

**2. Also, can one assign value labels to categorical variables in a few lines of code ?**

 - Most of my categorical variables are 0 = No / 1 = Yes.

 - Note that the value set in the dictionary file are the value labels.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/s882f4/efficient_relabeling_of_300_variables_and/

Answer (score 1):

Question 1. I don't see that there is a way in any language to avoid defining value labels separately for two variables Relationship to Household Head and Sex. What would be "inefficient" about that?

Question 2. You can assign a label to several variables at once, as is documented in the `help` and the associated manual entry.

```
  label def yesno 1 Yes 0 No 

  label val foo bar CO5-CO72 yesno
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your variables that use (for example) the value labels male/female end in "_sex" you could use a loop to assign labels (edited to show examples without loops as suggested in comment).

```
label def sex_lab 2 female 1 male

foreach var of varlist *_sex {
  label values `var' sex_lab
}
```

or without a loop:

```
label def sex_lab 2 female 1 male
label values *_sex sex_lab
```

Alternatively create a list of the variables you want to assign a particular label to:

```
local LIST_MY_VARS "lc04_sex foo bar"

forvalues i=1/2 {
   local my_var: word `i' of `LIST_MY_VARS'
   label values `my_var' sex_lab
}
```

or without a loop:

```
label values LIST_MY_VARS sex_lab
```

Comment: These approaches make a loop out if what can be expressed as a single statement in each case.

Comment: That's a great point!